# What should we name our chat room?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

Exactly five months ago (to the day), [Change name of chat room?](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/change-name-of-chat-room) was asked. The consensus was that it was too early, and so the whole thing stopped. Now that the site's much older, the time seems riper.

What should we name [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20403)? Another thing that was implicit was that "Engineering" is a bit boring; let's make it something more interesting.

Comment: This probably goes without saying - but [votes on meta are different](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).  In a discussion based question like this, votes merely mean "I agree" or "I disagree" with a suggested name for the chat room.  If you're new to meta participation, don't be upset if your suggestion is down voted.  Likewise, don't be too overly excited if you get lots of up votes too.  :-D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The Skunk Works

An homage to some of the best black engineering projects out there and [some of the folks who made them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skunk_Works).

The term has since been applied to other top-secret design facilities.

From the above-linked WP article:

> The designation ["skunk works" or "skunkworks"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skunkworks_project) is widely used in
> business, engineering, and technical fields to describe a group within
> an organization given a high degree of autonomy and unhampered by
> bureaucracy, tasked with working on advanced or secret projects.

Comment: [Care to mark this as answered?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20403/the-skunk-works)

Comment: @GlenH7 Sorry, I was away. Done.

Comment: NP.  [The rename only took place today anyway.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22595267#22595267)

Answer (score 5):

## The Drawing Board

As in, "Back to the . . ."

It's not exactly a place, but it has a nice ring to it.

Comment: Bit too close to [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/21/the-whiteboard) for my tastes.

Comment: @Air - Hey now, what's wrong with "The Whiteboard?"

Comment: @GlenH7 Nothing wrong with it, I just would like to see us distinguish ourselves, and they could be easily confused since a whiteboard is essentially a type of drawing board.

Answer (score 3):

## The Workshop

or just

## The Shop

Comment: +1 specifically for the latter, which brings to mind the expression "talking shop"

Comment: [Woodworking already has the first.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22025/the-workshop) The second seems like it could be (*could*) confused with the Woodworking chat.

Comment: @HDE226868 Hoist by my own petard!

Answer (score 3):

## Think Tank

Comment: I like this one.

Answer (score 2):

## Loose Screws

or, for those who prefer [the public house approach](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv287.shtml) (a la "The Prancing Pony"):

## The Loose Screw

Answer (score 1):

## Nuts and Bolts

---

Comment: Only if it gets a subtitle to complete the juvenile chant, i.e. "we got ..."

Answer (score 1):

#### [Signal:Noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio)

or

#### [Signal-to-Noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio)

---

Comment: I prefer Signal:Noise

Comment: I prefer Noise:Noise ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Moving Parts

Answer (score -1):

## De ingeneis

There was engineering before Renaissance but Renaissance Artist-Engineers were the ones that codified engineering. [Taccola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taccola) was an engineer that wrote De ingeneis (Concerning engines). His works were studied by other Renaissance engineers such as [Da Vinci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo_da_Vinci#Engineering_and_inventions) or [Francesco di Giorgio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francesco_di_Giorgio). Naming chat De ingeneis can be a conversation starter.

Answer (score -2):

## Experimental Station

To be a place where new ideas are born.

Answer (score -2):

#### Engineering

---

<sub>*I thought the existing name should be given a chance too.*</sub>

Comment: A chance to *die!*

Comment: @Air: 

James Bond: Do you expect me to talk?

Auric Goldfinger: No, Mr. Bond, I expect you to die!

Comment: While I disagree with the idea, thanks for putting this one up there. I should have remembered to do that.

Comment: @HDE226868 - Now you have a chance to down vote it.  :-)

Comment: @GlenH7 I did so. You can't upvote it, though - if you wanted to. :P